# delete multiple row sqlite android Error

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have write below code

```
String strId = "1,2"
try {
        myDB = myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    }
    myDB = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String strQuery = "delete from table1 where Id in ("
            + strId + ")";
    Log.w("strQuery", strQuery);
    myDB.execSQL(strQuery, null);

    myDbHelper.close();
```

But getting run time Error.

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: The error you're getting has nothing to do with your database. It's failing to execute the onClick handler for your button. Does the onClick handler in your activity have the correct name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I have got solutions as below

---

```
String strId = "1,2"
try {
    myDB = myDbHelper.openDataBase();
} catch (SQLException sqle) {
    throw sqle;
}
myDB = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
String strQuery = "delete from table1 where Id in ("
        + strId + ")";
Log.w("strQuery", strQuery);
myDB.execSQL(strQuery); // remove null

myDbHelper.close();
```

---

Just remove "null" in syntax myDB.execSQL(strQuery,null);

and it is work perfectly.